# Can't write string to file inside of NSSavePanel "ok" function

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

For some reason, I can only write a string to a file outside of `NSSavePanel`'s `ok` function. I need to write it as soon as the user says "OK, I do want to save that".

Here is my code:

```
//An IBAction that connects to the "Save" menu item.
@IBAction func SaveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    os_log("Save button pressed.")
    //Declares savePanel to be equal to NSSavePanel opens the save panel in a seperate window.
    let savePanel = NSSavePanel()
    savePanel.runModal()

    let textEntryController = EntryViewController()


    //Sets a placeholder of the text we're going to write.
    func ok(_ sender: Any?){

        let entryPath = savePanel.url
        let entryFieldContents = textEntryController.entryTextField!;
        let entryText = (entryFieldContents.textStorage as NSAttributedString?)?.string
        let entryContent = entryText
        do {
            try entryContent?.write(to: entryPath!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        } catch {
            // failed to write file – bad permissions, bad filename, missing permissions, or more likely it can't be converted to the encoding
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where does your code come from?  There are so many examples here and there for `NSSavePanel`.

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssavepanel/1525357-runmodal) especially the section *Return Value*

Comment: Unfortunately you appear to be misunderstanding how code is structured, connected and flows.Ask yourself what is the connection between `savePanel` and `ok()`? Does the closeness of their declarations join them in some way? Make on belong to the other? When you've answered those and are happier about how code links together and flows, so you don't go down the same path again, follow @vadian's link to the specific documentation for this situation. HTH

Comment: Is this a sandboxed app?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `runModal()` you should use the more modern closure syntax:

```
let savePanel = NSSavePanel()
savePanel.begin { (response) in
    if response == .OK {
        // write it here
    }
}
```

Comment: "Instead of using runModal() you should use the more modern closure syntax"  Que!?  What's wrong with runModal?  I use it with NSSavePanel.

Comment: As indicated by the existence of this question, runModal() is not very intuitive. More importantly, using a closure allows you to keep the code executed after the dialog right there with the creation of the dialog. There's no advantage to using runModal over the closure, but there are disadvantages. That said, if you like it and it works for you and you know what you're doing, then continue using runModal. But for someone that doesn't know what's going on, I'd still recommend the closure.